# Page redirect to same page in php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have two pages let say `www.abcd/cont.php` and `www.abcd/sign.php` 
When i fill the form in `www.abcd/cont.php` and click submit , it shows an alert msg and redirect to the same page (i.e www.abcd/cont.php) itself .
But instead of redirection, it is going to `www.abcd/sign.php` page itself.

Here is my sign.php code

```
if(success){
echo echo '<script language="javascript">';
      echo 'alert("send")';
      echo '</script>';
} else {
 echo '<script language="javascript">';
      echo 'alert("Not send")';
      echo '</script>';
}
header("Location: http://www.abcd/cont.php");
      exit();
```

i am getting the alert msg but not redirect to that particular page(www.abcd/cont.php) when i click ok on alert message.
Can anyone suggest an idea to do this.

Comment: there is nothing in the above code that would redirect you to `sign.php` as you say - though your question seems a little ambiguous with `But instead of redirection, it is going to www.abcd/sign.php` and `but not redirect to that particular page(www.abcd/cont.php) `

Comment: I assume the question is "When I click submit in sign, it is SUPPOSED to alert and go to cont" Right?

Answer (score 0):

You can just change the URL in JavaScript:

```
if(success){
    echo '<script language="javascript">alert("send");window.location = "http://www.abcd/cont.php";</script>';
} else {
    echo '<script language="javascript">alert("Not send");</script>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that it is happening because you are already sending headers by using the `echo` function hence your `Location()` is not working, instead you can try this,

```
if(success){
echo echo '<script language="javascript">';
      echo 'alert("send")';
      echo 'window.location.href=http://www.abcd/cont.php;';
      echo '</script>';
} else {
 echo '<script language="javascript">';
      echo 'alert("Not send")';
      echo '</script>';
}
```